# jQuery Mobile buttons don't change to 'pressed' state immediately when pressed

Tags: javascript, ios, css, jquery-mobile, uiwebview

In a `UIWebView` containing a simple jQuery Mobile styled button, which looks like:

[image][image]

pressing it does not change it's appearance (to the 'pressed' state with greyish background) immediately, only after 200m~, the button appearance changes (if holding the press) as it should have been changed already.

I'm not referring to the infamous delayed "onclick" event triggering of UIWebView, just the 'pressed' appearance of a button that is not shown immediately when pressed.

how do I correct that?

I'm using jQuery Mobile v1.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line did the trick:
`$.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 0;`

Referenced from the jQuery Mobile Docs page-
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html